# HP envy x360 install issue

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, hp

So my laptop is an HP envy x360 from 2014 with an intel Haswell processor. I flashed ubuntu on an usb drive and when I get into the grub installation screen and hit “try ubuntu without installing” I am presented with a black screen.

I tried adding nomodeset to the boot options, disabled secure boot, tried legacy mode in the bios settings , all without success, if anyone owning an hp laptop knows how to fix my issue please hit me up. I’m getting desperate.

Comment: I don't have a solution yet but in any case Legacy is NOT the way.

Comment: See also: HP Pavillion X360 13-a220nw
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2359510 & 
[Guide] Install Ubuntu 18.04 on HP Spectre x360 13" 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2414086

Answer (score 0):

It appears that HP has messed up their BIOS configuration.

Please see this for a more detailed answer (by Boldos).

[Why won't my HP Envy x360 laptop with Ryzen 7 3700U boot Ubuntu live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162746/why-wont-my-hp-envy-x360-laptop-with-ryzen-7-3700u-boot-ubuntu-live-cd)