# Installation fails on HP Laptop (Windows OK)

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, uefi, hp, amd-ryzen

I want to install Linux as a dual boot alongside Windows on an HP Laptop with a 3000 Series Ryzen APU which has Vega Graphics.  I just replaced the SSD with a larger SSD  and partitioned about 300 GB for my Linux System. Windows runs OK, but when I go to boot to a live disc to install Ubuntu, I get a black screen when installation starts.

I have tried doing the Nomodeset command and no Luck. I have also done a BIOS Update, Disabled Secure Boot, and used a Day 0 Ubuntu ISO. I

How do I troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Did the HP UEFI update include the AMD fixes released about a month ago? https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ryzen-3000-BIOS-Update-Good Are you using Ubuntu 19.04 as that is the only one they claim to have fixed. I might try 19.10, but realize it is not yet final. It does install & work on my system (Intel based), but I only use LTS versions as main working install.

Comment: Im not sure if that UEFI Update fixed a specific issue, I just did it as a troubleshooting step. I tried installing it with 19.10 Eoan Ermine and it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

I got it installed on my laptop same model using this... Courtesy of user boldos

[Why won't my HP Envy x360 laptop with Ryzen 7 3700U boot Ubuntu live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162746/why-wont-my-hp-envy-x360-laptop-with-ryzen-7-3700u-boot-ubuntu-live-cd/1163672#1163672)

Upgrading to the 5.2.11 kernel after installation boots without mods.

Comment: Im not gonna lie Im just getting started with this, extracting the table from windows and stuff I have tried to look up and see the process to doing that and I cant find it, do you have a more in depth guide with screen shots or anything? Im sorry, Im guessing this is the issue I just cant replicate it. I tried doing the simple option and it works but ubuntu crashes during the boot process when the 5 dots come up

Comment: Download his image from the discussion. I got it banged out in an hour or 2 without extracting anything. Just using the sudo cp command to move the files he says between the 2 kernel packages. And once you use ukuu to update to 5.2.11 you don't need to move the files